# How do we enable application insights profile for a service fabric application running on asp.net core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights

**Code:**

```
 {
      "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
    Telemetry:
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": ""
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you want and what you did?

Comment: did you see this: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric

Comment: There is a nuget package for Application Insights specifically for Service Fabric applications. This can be added to each of your reliable services and you can choose to send telemetry to a new or existing App Insights resource. The benefits of this package is you get specific information about Service Fabric in the telemetry sent such as context about the service, partition, node in an unhandled exception as well as an App Map showing a visual representation of your services communicating with one another https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-servicefabric Here is the full tutorial

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we just chose **Project > Add Application Insights Telemetry** via VS for our .NET Core 2.0 Stateful ASP.NET Core web application to set up Application Insights. After configuration, the `appsettings.json` file would look like as follows:

```html
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "{your-Instrumentation-Key}"
  }
}
```

Moreover, you could follow the tutorial [Microsoft Application Insights for Service Fabric](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric) mentioned by LoekD to choose the proper library based on your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a really flexible solution then you can see on [this repository](https://github.com/DeHeerSoftware/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring) which contains an Azure Service Fabric application that integrates Application Insights with Service Fabric using structured logging.